# Giving each widget unique data

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-widget, android-service

I'd like users to be able to create widgets that each have their own state (specifically, two ints that will most likely be unique to each widget). When widgets are clicked, the ints will be used to do something. I thought I'd be able to do this by adding the data as extras to an intent and using the setOnClickPendingIntent() method to give each widget a unique intent. However, it seems that this ends up giving each widget the same configuration as the initial widget. Below is some relevant code:

**WidgetConfig.java** - onClick() method for "Save Widget" button

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                                     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_layout);

    //pass data to service using intent
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilterService.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("alpha", 255 - alpha);
    newIntent.putExtra("red", red);

    Log.e("WidgetConfig", "Put in alpha: " + newIntent.getIntExtra("alpha", -1) + ", red: " + newIntent.getIntExtra("red", -1));

    //set intent to be executed when widget is clicked and update widget
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, newIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWidget, pending);

    manager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);

    //Pass result back to OS to create widget
    Intent resultVal = new Intent();
    resultVal.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultVal);
    finish();
}
```

**FilterService.java** - this is the onStartCommand() method where I'd like to recover the data

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int alpha = intent.getIntExtra("alpha", 256);
    int red = intent.getIntExtra("red", 256);
    Log.e("FilterService", "alpha = " + alpha);
    Log.e("FilterService", "red = " + red);
}
```

The logcat output looks something like this:

```
E/WidgetConfig: Put in alpha: 143, red: 105
E/FilterService: alpha = 143
E/FilterService: red = 105
E/WidgetConfig: Put in alpha: 9, red: 254
E/FilterService: alpha = 143
E/FilterService: red = 105
```

This code works well for the first widget, but all widgets added after that receive the same intent extras. Am I missing something? Or is there a better way to give the widgets the data they need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really common issue -- I suspect most widget developers have run into this. The second half of the overview for PendingIntent explains that, as you found, changing only the extras in an intent does not cause Android to make a separate PendingIntent:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

As the doc says, there are a different ways to solve this. One that I've used is to put the extra data into a URI, and set that URI as the intent's data. I think the code below will work, although in my app I've also had other parts of the URI besides just the query parameters. But at least with some tweaking it should work:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilterService.class);
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.appendQueryParameter("alpha", Integer.toString(255 - alpha));
builder.appendQueryParameter("red", Integer.toString(red));
newIntent.setData(builder.build());
```

Then in your service, you would do this:

```
int alpha;
int red;
Uri uri = intent.getData();
if (uri != null) {
    try {
        alpha = Integer.parseInt(uri.getQueryParameter("alpha"));
        red = Integer.parseInt(uri.getQueryParameter("red"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //TODO either ignore or have default alpha / red values
    }
}
```